# Non Clustered index being ignored

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have `archived_events` table with the following indexes.

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_archived_events_5] ON [dbo].[archived_events]
    (
        [account_id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[archived_events] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_archived_events] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [event_type] DESC,
    [id] DESC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

The problem is that when I execute the following query, I see in the execution plan that it does Clusterd Index Scan on [PK_archived_events]

```
SELECT *                                  
FROM   archived_events ae WITH(nolock) 
WHERE     ( 30 = ae.[account_id] )
```

What is the reason that the non clustered index is being ignored?

*Also a note that this is SQL Azure, not sure if it matters.*

Comment: How many rows are in the table? How many match `30 = ae.[account_id]`?

Comment: @MartinSmith 4 million rows...

Comment: @MartinSmith 717536 match 30 = ae.[account_id]

Comment: That's 18% of the table so it probably reckons it only has to scan about 50 rows to get the `TOP 10`. What if you try with a more selective predicate?

Comment: @MartinSmith I have tried many queries, it always behaves the same.

Comment: Are the statistics updated on the table?  This shouldn't matter, but try changing the query to ae.account_id = 30 and remove the no lock just to test.

Comment: @BartCzernicki I did your suggested changes, but it did not help. An interesting thing that I noted is that if I do count(*), it does use the IX_archived_events_5 non clustered index.

Comment: I'd guess this has to do with the use of 'select *' versus 'select [column1], [column2]'.  Try pulling back what you actually need rather than the whole width of the table.

Comment: @BenThul Ben I think you are correct,  the * probably makes it a non-covering index.

Comment: @BenThul I have tried your suggestion and I see that the non clustered is being used if I pull back only the primary key. If I add any other column, the clustered index is being used. Is it possible that this happens because of few nvarchar(max) columns of the table?

Comment: That's possible. My guess is that your PK is also the clustered index. You can make your NC index used by using include columns. Every NC index has the cluster key as include columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table had nvarchar(max) columns that interfered with the index. I have converted them to  nvarchar(n) and the index works now.